# Pygame code not executing (window won't open)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am currently trying to re create Pong in pygame. This is my code:

```
import sys, pygame 
from pygame.locals import *


FPS = 60

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

WINDOWWIDTH = 400
WINDOWHEIGHT = 300
LINETHICKNESS = 10 
PADDLESIZE = 50
PADDLEOFFSET = 20 

def drawArena():
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((BLACK))
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ((0,0),(WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT)), LINETHICKNESS*2)
    pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ((WINDOWWIDTH/2),0),((WINDOWWIDTH/2),WINDOWHEIGHT), (LINETHICKNESS/4))

def drawPaddle(paddle):
    if paddle.bottom > (WINDOWHEIGHT - LINETHICKNESS):
       paddle.bottom = WINDOWHEIGHT - LINETHICKNESS
    elif paddle.top > LINETHICKNESS:
        paddle.top = LINETHICKNESS
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, paddle)


def drawBall(ball): 
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ball) 

def moveBall(ball, ballDirX, ballDirY):
    ball.x += ballDirX
    ball.y += ballDirY
    return ball

def checkWallCollision(ball, ballDirX, ballDirY):
    if ball.top == (LINETHICKNESS) or ball.bottom == (WINDOWHEIGHT - LINETHICKNESS):
        ballDirY = ballDirY * -1
    if ball.left == (LINETHICKNESS) or ball.right == (WINDOWHEIGHT - LINETHICKNESS):
        ballDirX = ballDirX * -1
    return ballDirX, ballDirY

def checkPaddleCollision(ball, ballDirX, paddle1, paddle2):
    if ballDirX == -1 and paddle1.right == ball.left and paddle1.top < ball.top and paddle1.bottom > ball.bottom:
        return -1
    elif ballDirX == -1 and paddle2.left == ball.right and paddle2.top < ball.top and paddle2.bottom > ball.bottom:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1 

def checkPointScored(paddle1, ball, score, ballDirX):
    if ball.left == LINETHICKNESS:
        return 0
    elif ballDirX == -1 and paddle1.right == ball.left and paddle1.top < ball.top and paddle1.bottom > ball.bottom:
        score += 1
    elif ball.right == WINDOWWIDTH - LINETHICKNESS:
        score += 5 
        return score
    else: return score 

def aI(ball, ballDirX, paddle2):
    if ballDirX == -1:
        if paddle2.centery < (WINDOWHEIGHT/2):
            paddle2.y += 1
        elif paddle2.centery > (WINDOWHEIGHT/2):
            paddle2.y -= 1

    elif ballDirX == 1:
        if paddle2.centery < ball.centery:
            paddle2.y += 1
        else:
            paddle2.y -=1
    return paddle2

def displayScore(score):
    resultSurf = BASICFONT.render('Score = %s' %(score), True, WHITE)
    resultRect = resultSurf,get_rect()
    resultRect.topleft = WINDOWWIDTH = 150, 25
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(resultSurf, resultRect)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    global DISPLAYSURF
    global BASICFONT, BASICFONTSIZE 
    BASICFONTSIZE = 20 
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', BASICFONTSIZE)

    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')

    ballX = WINDOWWIDTH/2 - LINETHICKNESS/2
    ballY = WINDOWHEIGHT/2 - LINETHICKNESS/2
    playerOnePosition = (WINDOWHEIGHT - PADDLESIZE) /2 
    playerTwoPosition = (WINDOWHEIGHT - PADDLESIZE) /2
    score = 0

    ballDirX = -1
    ballDirY = -1

    paddle1 = pygame.Rect(PADDLEOFFSET, playerOnePosition, LINETHICKNESS, PADDLESIZE)
    paddle2 = pygame.Rect(WINDOWWIDTH - PADDLEOFFSET - LINETHICKNESS, playerTwoPosition, LINETHICKNESS, PADDLESIZE)
    ball = pygame.Rect(ballX, ballY, LINETHICKNESS, LINETHICKNESS)
    drawArena()
    drawPaddle(paddle1)
    drawPaddle(paddle2)
    drawBall(ball)

    while True: #main game loop
        pygame.event.get()
        pygame.event.pump()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        drawArena()
        drawPaddle(paddle1)
        drawPaddle(paddle2)
        drawBall(ball)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

My problem is when I run the file through the shell the output is:

```
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) on Windows (64 bits).
This is the Pyzo interpreter with integrated event loop for TK.
Type 'help' for help, type '?' for a list of *magic* commands.
Running script: "H:\pong.py"
```

However, the window that I created is not appearing and it seems as if it has crashed as soon as it had been opened or something of the sort. Help me find out what this is, please!

Comment: Assuming that your code is posted with the actual indentation, nothing is actually being executed - the last two lines that should invoke `main()` are indented, so that they are a part of main, rather than at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

The code below runs OK, shows in the command line output the events and makes it possible to process events and close the window.

Besides the already mentioned (see comments) indentation problem, there was a problem with capturing events (see out-commented lines), so that it was not possible to process the events and to close the raised window.

```
import sys, pygame 
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 60

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

WINDOWWIDTH   = 400
WINDOWHEIGHT  = 300
LINETHICKNESS = 10 
PADDLESIZE    = 50
PADDLEOFFSET  = 20 

def drawArena():
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((BLACK))
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ((0,0),(WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT)), LINETHICKNESS*2)
    pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ((int(WINDOWWIDTH/2)),0),((int(WINDOWWIDTH/2)),WINDOWHEIGHT), (int(LINETHICKNESS/4)))

def drawPaddle(paddle):
    if paddle.bottom > (WINDOWHEIGHT - LINETHICKNESS):
       paddle.bottom = WINDOWHEIGHT - LINETHICKNESS
    elif paddle.top > LINETHICKNESS:
        paddle.top = LINETHICKNESS
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, paddle)

def drawBall(ball): 
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ball) 

def moveBall(ball, ballDirX, ballDirY):
    ball.x += ballDirX
    ball.y += ballDirY
    return ball

def checkWallCollision(ball, ballDirX, ballDirY):
    if ball.top == (LINETHICKNESS) or ball.bottom == (WINDOWHEIGHT - LINETHICKNESS):
        ballDirY = ballDirY * -1
    if ball.left == (LINETHICKNESS) or ball.right == (WINDOWHEIGHT - LINETHICKNESS):
        ballDirX = ballDirX * -1
    return ballDirX, ballDirY

def checkPaddleCollision(ball, ballDirX, paddle1, paddle2):
    if ballDirX == -1 and paddle1.right == ball.left and paddle1.top < ball.top and paddle1.bottom > ball.bottom:
        return -1
    elif ballDirX == -1 and paddle2.left == ball.right and paddle2.top < ball.top and paddle2.bottom > ball.bottom:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1 

def checkPointScored(paddle1, ball, score, ballDirX):
    if ball.left == LINETHICKNESS:
        return 0
    elif ballDirX == -1 and paddle1.right == ball.left and paddle1.top < ball.top and paddle1.bottom > ball.bottom:
        score += 1
    elif ball.right == WINDOWWIDTH - LINETHICKNESS:
        score += 5 
        return score
    else: return score 

def aI(ball, ballDirX, paddle2):
    if ballDirX == -1:
        if paddle2.centery < (WINDOWHEIGHT/2):
            paddle2.y += 1
        elif paddle2.centery > (WINDOWHEIGHT/2):
            paddle2.y -= 1

    elif ballDirX == 1:
        if paddle2.centery < ball.centery:
            paddle2.y += 1
        else:
            paddle2.y -=1
    return paddle2

def displayScore(score):
    resultSurf = BASICFONT.render('Score = %s' %(score), True, WHITE)
    resultRect = resultSurf,get_rect()
    resultRect.topleft = WINDOWWIDTH = 150, 25
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(resultSurf, resultRect)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    global DISPLAYSURF
    global BASICFONT, BASICFONTSIZE 
    BASICFONTSIZE = 20 
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', BASICFONTSIZE)

    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')

    ballX = WINDOWWIDTH/2 - LINETHICKNESS/2
    ballY = WINDOWHEIGHT/2 - LINETHICKNESS/2
    playerOnePosition = (WINDOWHEIGHT - PADDLESIZE) /2 
    playerTwoPosition = (WINDOWHEIGHT - PADDLESIZE) /2
    score = 0

    ballDirX = -1
    ballDirY = -1

    paddle1 = pygame.Rect(PADDLEOFFSET, playerOnePosition, LINETHICKNESS, PADDLESIZE)
    paddle2 = pygame.Rect(WINDOWWIDTH - PADDLEOFFSET - LINETHICKNESS, playerTwoPosition, LINETHICKNESS, PADDLESIZE)
    ball = pygame.Rect(ballX, ballY, LINETHICKNESS, LINETHICKNESS)
    drawArena()
    drawPaddle(paddle1)
    drawPaddle(paddle2)
    drawBall(ball)

    while True: #main game loop
        # pygame.event.get()
        # pygame.event.pump()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print("event", event)
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        drawArena()
        drawPaddle(paddle1)
        drawPaddle(paddle2)
        drawBall(ball)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```